# Magento 2.3.4 problem with product image load end with 503 error code

Tags: image, magento2, product, admin

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
https://wymienolej.pl/media/catalog/product/cache/b8707abefda280ae22e1939ab4607ef1/e/p/eplus12fe007.png
```

Magento loads very small thumbnail image (like in admin page list) instead of normall small image of product. I have to refresh page to load correctly. Size of image is 900kb. Is it too big and I should upload lower res image for small image ?